# window.VARIABLE_NAME is not working

Tags: javascript

`window.VARIABLE_NAME` is not working. I am getting following error, please guide me.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.
```

I wrote following code.

```
var window.testing
```

Comment: windows. usually means that you are declaring a variable at global scope which means it will be accessible anywhere in your JS. Normally this is to be avoided unless it is extremely important. You should use var to define variables at local function level scope.

Answer (score 5):

You don't use `var` for defined varables.

In this case `window` is already defined as the `Window` object.

To set a property on this object, simply use

```
window.testing = "hello";
```

Read more about `var` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: When this answer solves your problem, please note that using global variables in Javascript is not suggested unless you know what are you doing. [Read more why here](https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a property of an object, not creating a variable. Don't use the `var` keyword.

Comment: I used var keyword too as following 
var window.testing

Comment: actually I want to use it in for loop. 
in for loop I have an if condition and in if condition I made array
so that I can access it outside loop. 

but I am not getting that variable outside loop. 

I tried following both statements but nothing working 

var window.variablename;
OR
var window[vriablename];

Comment: There's no need to use an explicit global just to access a variable outside a loop, but as I said, "Just don't use the var keyword": `window.testing`.